# Is f(x) = x smooth?

Tags: functions

It may sound too basic to even be a question, but I couldn't find a straight answer in Wolfram Alpha, Wolfram Mathworld or Wikipedia. Several other examples of more complicated functions are given.

In [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothFunction.html) it is written that

> A smooth function is a function that has continuous derivatives up to
>   some desired order over some domain. (...) The number of continuous
>   derivatives necessary for a function to be considered smooth depends
>   on the problem at hand, and may vary from two to infinity.

$f(x) = x$ has derivative 1 of the first order and 0 of second order, so I would say based on this it has at least 2 derivatives. I think it also  has an infinite number of derivatives which are also 0.

Another page on [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-InfinityFunction.html) says the following:

> A $C^{\infty}$ function is a function that is differentiable for all degrees of differentiation. (...) All polynomials are $C^{\infty}$. (...) $C^{\infty}$ functions are also called "smooth" (...).

Since $f(x) = x$ is a polynomial, I'm concluding that the paragraphs above mean it is also smooth.

Comment: I also think they are smooth

Comment: "Smooth" runs the gamut from continuously differentiable to $C^\infty,$ and even that is probably too narrow a spectrum. There is no one fixed definition. In the literature you'll often see things like "for the purposes of this paper, "smooth" will mean ___," where "____" is a precise definition.

Comment: @CarstenS The question is in the title: Is the function f(x)=x  smooth?

Comment: I made an attempt to answer it based on what I found, and I showed my reasoning to provide something to the question. So yes, the question contains an answer, but I still was not sure if this holds up, and I was still interested in further information and others' input.

Comment: @zhw.: Is there any definition of "smooth" that does *not* apply to $f(x)=x$?

Comment: I've never seen one.

Comment: @celtschk any such definition must be boring and useless...

Answer (score 32):

A function is smooth is it has derivatives of infinite order. $f(x) = x$ is smooth because it has infinitely many derivatives which are all 0, except for the first one. Polynomials are smooth because eventually their derivatives are 0.

Comment: Is it agreed upon that "smooth" = $C^\infty$ diffable?

Comment: Yes, that's the standard definition

Comment: @MichaelMenke Not so sure that is standard.

Comment: I wouldn't be so confused if it was standard ha. You flip a text book on differential geometry, says "smooth =$ C^\infty$ diffable, you flip a text book on wavelet, says smooth = $C^k$ diffable...

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant yeah technically smooth is $C^\infty$, but many times for all the calculations we only need our function to be $C^1$ or $C^2$ or something.. so we abuse the notation and we call those function "smooth", which basically comes to mean "it's regular enough to employ all the theorems we need with no headaches"

Comment: I've heard smooth mean that the first derivative is continuous.

Comment: $x\mapsto x$ satisfies _every definition_ you guys have given.

Comment: What are _"derivatives of infinite order"_?

Comment: @JiK: While he surely meant derivatives of arbitrary order, a straightforfard definition of a derivative of infinite order would be $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm d^nf}{\mathrm dx^n}$ provided that limit exists. For example, the infiniteth derivative of any polynomial would be $0$, and the infinifteth derivative of $\exp(x)$ would be $\exp(x)$. Indeed, since that infiniteth derivative could well be differentiable itself (as the two examples are), one could identify this infinity with $\omega$ and continue with $\frac{\mathrm d^{\omega+1}f}{\mathrm dx^{\omega+1}}$. and so on.

Comment: Typo found: is -> if

Answer (score 23):

Yes, the identity function has derivatives of every finite order, and is therefore smooth. It doesn't matter that most of the derivatives are $0$ everywhere -- being $0$ is a perfectly cromulent way to exist.

Comment: I had to look that word up. Between this and popularizing _schadenfreude_, _The Simpsons_ has really influenced the language, hasn't it?

Comment: @columbus8myhw yes, it's certainly embiggened our vocabulary

Answer (score 5):

You may be having issues with the difference between existence and triviality.

If $f(x)=x$ then

$f(x)=x$ is continuouss

$f'(x)=1$ is continuous

$f''(x)=0$ is continuous

$f'''(x)=0$ is continuous

etc...

So all its derivatives are continuous. On the other hand, take $g(x)=x\times|x|$

$g(x)=x\times|x|$ is continuous

$g'(x)=\frac{|x|}2$ is continuous

$g''(x) = \frac12$ if $x>0$, $g''(x)=-\frac12$ if $x<0$ $g''(0)$ is undefined

Clearly $g''$ is not continuous because of $g''(0)$ not existing, and so $g$ only has two derivatives.

Intuitively, all of $f$'s derivatives have no breaks in their graph ($y=0$ is simply a nice line), while $g''$ graph has a gaping hole in it at $x=0$.

Comment: Funny definition of a "gaping" hole, that is a nothingth of a unit wide :)

Comment: @thepeer Is a unit more or less than the gap of the grand canyon?

Comment: Does it matter, seeing as we're talking about a nothingth of it?