# Derivatives of ordinal order

Tags: real-analysis, ordinals

This question actually arises from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1408293/34930) to another question, which contains the sentence

> A function is smooth is it has derivatives of infinite order.

While the author surely didn't actually mean $\frac{\mathrm d^\infty f}{\mathrm dx^\infty}$, a comment on that post got me to think about that.

I've come to the following definition:

Be $\alpha$ an arbitrary ordinal. Then the $\alpha$th derivative of $f(x)$ is defined as follows, provided the used derivatives/limits exist:
$$\frac{\mathrm d^\alpha f}{\mathrm dx^\alpha} =
\begin{cases}
f & \text{if }\alpha = 0\\
\frac{d}{dx}\,\frac{\mathrm d^\beta f}{\mathrm dx^\beta} & \text{if } \alpha=\beta+1\\
\lim_{\beta\to\alpha}\frac{\mathrm d^\beta f}{\mathrm dx^\beta} & \text{if } \alpha \text{ is a limit ordinal}
\end{cases}$$
Here the limit is meant pointwise.

Here are a few cases:

- If $f(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial, $\frac{\mathrm d^\omega f}{\mathrm dx^\omega}=0$.
- If $f(x) = \exp(a x)$, then
  $$\frac{\mathrm d^\omega f}{\mathrm dx^\omega}=
  \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if } -1 \le a < 1\\
  \exp(x) & \text{if } a = 1\\
  \text{does not exist} & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$
- $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ don't have a $\omega$th derivative.

Also the $C^n$ classes can be generalized in a straightforward way: A function is in $\tilde C^\alpha$ if for every $\beta\in\alpha$, the $\beta$th derivative of $f$ exists and is continuous. For finite $n$, we have $C^n=\tilde C^{n+1}$ ($\tilde C^0$ would be all functions). Moreover, $C^\infty = \tilde C^\omega$. If the $\omega$th derivative exists and is continuous, the function is in $\tilde C^{\omega+1}$.

Now my questions:

- Has anyone already considered such derivatives? Are they even useful somewhere?
- Is there an easy way to characterize the functions in $\tilde C^{\omega+1}$?
- Are there functions in $\tilde C^{\omega+1}$ whose $\omega$th derivative is neither $0$ nor $\exp(x)$? (Otherwise the ordinal order derivatives would be rather boring).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719382, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362873, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595317